# Sort steam by unearned Achievements?

Tags: steam

I want to order my steam games by "unearned achievments" aka achievements I haven't gotten yet because I am trying to 100% every game I have.

Does anyone know how to do that?
If that's not possible can you somehow sort every game in the Categories by hand?

Comment: @KevinTheGreat But that's already a duplicate of a duplicate. I suggest resolving it as duplicate of 45723 instead, otherwise there's a 4-question-duplicate chain.

Comment: i looked at the other questions you meantioned and yes,it is a duplicate,i didn'T know this tho because i literally just joined ._.

Comment: @MajesticRhino no problem, it is just done to keep the site clean. Hope the answers there help you.